# Why does Chrome show overlapping text?

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome, news articles at: 
http://www.theprovince.com

with a leading photo and caption show the caption text overlapped with the body text. I have an image but as a new user here I'm not allowed to upload it.

It happens at that site almost always, here's an example from today:
http://www.theprovince.com/sports/Canucks+Blackhawks+collision+Titanic+proportions/5721421/story.html

It rarely happens elsewhere. The same link works fine in Internet Explorer so I'm guessing it's a Chrome issue.

It's been like this for many months, I read the site almost everyday. I click on "Print this Article" to get a proper look at it, but it's annoying, hope someone has the answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you include a link to the photo, I'll embed it into your question for you (or someone else will beat me to it, heheh).

Comment: The issue most likely has a lot more to do with the web site designers not testing their code in [the major web browsers](http://www.lumbercartel.ca/resources/web-browsers.pl).  (When I encounter web sites that don't work properly in certain web browsers, I try to notify the webmaster; if there is a statement against support for a particular web browser, then I'll try to send a complaint to the sales/marketing departments instead.)

Comment: I can't replicate this issue with Chrome 13.0.782.220 on Windows.  Do you have any extensions installed that might affect layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate it using with Chrome 15.0.874.120 on Windows.
[image: Overlapping text]

It seems to have disappeared now that I have updated to version 15.0.874.121 (released 30 minutes ago). Try updating and see if you still get the problem

Comment: Yup, that did it, thanks! I managed a re-test and manual update before Google Update would have done it for me, and sure enough that fixed the problem. I could have saved you all the trouble if I had waited one more day ... figures! BTW, glad to join here and StackOverflow, these sites are awesome.